# How to use keyset pagination?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, keyset-pagination

Suppose I have total 800 eligible rows in database which is ordered by a column `requisitionid` in descending order. I want to display the records in 80 pages each page having 10 rows. We are using `requisitionid` as seek predicate. So the predicate  should be less than or greater than? As the query will progress from UI (Angular + primeNG), I want to send just one parameter - `requisitionid`. If it is less than query, then the query will be `SELECT ... FROM ... where requisitionid < ?`, so here we are talking about first row. If we go for greater than query i.e. `SELECT ... FROM ... where requisitionid > ?`, here we are talking about last row of the page.

Please refer to [Life without offset](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

**EDIT**
Actual code:

```
with topten as (SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 10   
        REQN.CASE_ID
        ,userContact2.BV_First_Name + ' ' + userContact2.BV_Last_Name ReQCreater
        ,REQN.BV_Internal_Job_Title
        ,REQN.BV_Posted_Job_Title as postedJobTitle
        ,REQN.BV_Status
        ,REQN.BV_Taleo_Id
        ,REQN.BV_WD_PositionID
        ,jobcode.BV_Job_Code
        ,loc.BV_LocationCode
        ,loc.BV_LocationName
        ,D.BV_Division_Code AS 'divCode',

        ISNULL(loc.BV_Address1,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(loc.BV_Address1,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + ISNULL(loc.BV_Address2,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(loc.BV_Address2,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' END
        + ISNULL(loc.BV_City,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(loc.BV_City,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + ISNULL(loc.BV_State,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(loc.BV_State,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE (case when ISNULL(loc.BV_ZipCode,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' END) END
        + ISNULL(loc.BV_ZipCode,'') AS locationAddress
        from dbo.CW_V_REQN as REQN  
        INNER JOIN dbo.CW_TL_Requisition__Location_Master as reqLocLink on REQN.CASE_ID = reqLocLink.FROM_ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CW_V_LOCTMAST as loc on loc.CASE_ID = reqLocLink.TO_ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CW_TL_UserContactInfo__Location_Master as locUserLink on locUserLink.TO_ID =  loc.CASE_ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CW_V_USERCONT as userContact on userContact.CASE_ID = locUserLink.FROM_ID 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CW_TL_Requisition__Department as reqDeptLink on REQN.CASE_ID = reqDeptLink.FROM_ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CW_V_DEPARTME as dept on dept.CASE_ID = reqDeptLink.TO_ID 
        LEFT  JOIN dbo.CW_TL_UserContactInfo__Department_Master as deptUserLink on dept.CASE_ID=deptUserLink.TO_ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CW_TL_Requisition__Job_Code as reqJobLink on REQN.CASE_ID = reqJobLink.FROM_ID 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CW_V_JOBCODE as jobcode on jobcode.CASE_ID = reqJobLink.TO_ID 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CW_V_USERCONT as userContact2 on (userContact2.BV_Login_Name = REQN.CREATED_BY) 
        LEFT JOIN CW_TL_LocationMaster__Division_Master LD ON (LD.FROM_ID = loc.CASE_ID) 
        LEFT JOIN CW_V_DIVISION D ON (D.CASE_ID = LD.TO_ID) 
        WHERE userContact.BV_Login_Name = @LOGINNAME

        AND REQN.CASE_ID < @MINCASEIDPREVPAGE
        ORDER BY REQN.CASE_ID DESC
        )
```

select topten.*
, T.*
from topten 
cross join (select min(case_id) as min from topten) as T

Comment: That's a great article you link to. But what's the problem you have? Show us some code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For key based pagination on a descending key, the WHERE clause predicate should be `<` for the next page and `>` for the previous page. Also, the `ORDER BY` clause for the previous page needs to be `ASC` (for the TOP predicate) along an outer `DESC` (for the descending key display sequence). Below is an example.

```
--create test table with sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(
    requisitionid int PRIMARY KEY
);
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1000 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num  FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT num
FROM t1000
WHERE num <= 800;
GO

--query for first page (page 1) on descending key (returns 800-791)
SELECT TOP(10) requisitionid
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY requisitionid DESC;
GO

--query for next page (page 2) on descending key (returns 790-781)
DECLARE @LastRequisitionIdOnPage int = 791;
SELECT TOP(10) requisitionid
FROM YourTable
WHERE requisitionid < @LastRequisitionIdOnPage
ORDER BY requisitionid DESC;
GO

--query for previous page (page 1) on descending key (returns 800-791)
DECLARE @FirstRequisitionIdOnPage int = 790;
SELECT requisitionid
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(10) requisitionid
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE requisitionid > @FirstRequisitionIdOnPage
    ORDER BY requisitionid ASC
    ) AS prev_page
ORDER BY requisitionid DESC;;
GO
```

Comment: Hi Dan, fantastic, I was thinking on similar lines that we need different queries for first page and subsequent pages. After implementing, I will accept your answer in a day or two.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta, you could use the next page query for the first page as well if you pass a higher value for @LastRequisitionIdOnPage than exists in the database (e.g. `2147483647` for int). I didn't do that in my answer for clarity.

Comment: I am facing this issue now. There are gaps in requisition id like 15447,15446,15445,15444,15443,15442,15440,15439,15437,15435,15433,15432,15431,15430,15429,15428,15427,15426,14426,14425,14424 etc. How to account for  gaps? I do not want to use rownumber as it is very slow.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta, why do care about gaps? The `requisitioned` values used in these queries are existing ones so one can page forward/back regardless of gaps.

Comment: I have edited my question to include snippet of actual stored proc. This actually works, I have used your idea of using a very large number in the first page for @MINCASEIDPREVPAGE. Problem I am facing is if user paginates the pages sequentially then there is no problem, but if user say after first page clicks the 5th page in the GUI, it takes the user to the 2nd page only not the 5th page, though the  GUI tells user is in 5th page.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta, how do you know that there is a 5th page to be returned? This key based pagination technique works well with next/previous/first/last but not so well with navigation by page number because page numbers are unknown until visited and one cannot always rely on no gaps in such a pagination key. You could cache the first/last values of each visited page to allow backward navigation to an already visited pages by number, which assumes the result set does not change since the first time the query was executed.

Comment: thanks. I also thought on the same line - if you use keyset pagination, use prev, next in place of numbered links.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, you should be able to use the follow clause at the end of your `SELECT` query:

`OFFSET (@Page * 10) ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

If this is not what you are looking for, please post your current query so we can see what you are doing now.

Comment: I think OP asked for keyset pagination, not offset pagination.